# Application not responding on releasing the camera using camera.release() android

Tags: android, android-camera

In my app I am capturing images automatically using a service.

From my service I am opening the camera activity.

Camera Activity

```
public class CameraActivity extends Activity {

private static final String TAG = "CameraDemo";
SharedPreferences pref;

CameraPreview preview;
Button click;
// enter email adress from where the email will be sent
String fromPassWord;
int cameraType;
private static final int FRONT_CAMERA = 0;
private static final int BACK_CAMERA = 1;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.camera);
    cameraType = getIntent().getIntExtra("cameraType",BACK_CAMERA);

    preview = new CameraPreview(this,cameraType);
    ((FrameLayout) findViewById(com.abc.xyz.R.id.preview)).addView(preview);
     handler.sendEmptyMessageDelayed(0, 100);
     Log.d(TAG, "onCreate'd");
}

Handler handler = new Handler() {
    public void handleMessage(android.os.Message msg) {
        try{
            if(preview.camera != null ){ 
                 preview.camera.takePicture(shutterCallback, rawCallback, jpegCallback);    
            }else{
                finish();                   
            }
        }catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            finish();                   
        }
    };
};

ShutterCallback shutterCallback = new ShutterCallback() {
    public void onShutter() {
        Log.d(TAG, "onShutter'd");
        Log.v(TAG, "onShutter'd");
    }
};

PictureCallback rawCallback = new PictureCallback() {
    public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onPictureTaken - raw");
        Log.v(TAG, "onPictureTaken - raw");
    }
};

PictureCallback jpegCallback = new PictureCallback() {
    public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
        try {
            //my method for storing image
            StoreByteImage(data, 75, "ImageName");
            Log.v("on picture taken", "picture callback");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Exception--------------------1");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finish();
    }
};
```

}

CameraPreview.java

```
class CameraPreview extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback{

private static final String TAG = "Preview";
SurfaceHolder mHolder;
public Camera camera;
int cameraType;
Context _context;
private static final int FRONT_CAMERA   = 0;
private static final int BACK_CAMERA    = 1;
//SurfaceHolder controls the surface size and format, edit the pixels in the surface, and monitor changes to the surface
CameraPreview(Context context, int type){
    super(context);
    //Return the SurfaceHolder providing access and control over this SurfaceView's underlying surface
    mHolder = getHolder();
    //Add a callback interface to this holder
    mHolder.addCallback(this);
    //Set the surface type
    mHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);

    this.cameraType =   type;
    _context    =   context;
}

//Create a surface
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder sHolder){

    if(cameraType == FRONT_CAMERA){
        try{
            camera  =   openFrontFacingCameraGingerbread();  //method to open camera...
            Log.v("cameraFornt", "value"+camera);
        }catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    }else{
        //do nothing
    }
    if(camera == null)
        return;

    try{
        camera.setPreviewDisplay(sHolder);

        //Installs a callback to be invoked for every preview frame in addition to displaying them on the screen
        camera.setOneShotPreviewCallback(new PreviewCallback(){

            //Called as preview frames are displayed
            public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera arg1){

                CameraPreview.this.invalidate();
            }
        });
    } catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

//called immediately before a surface is being destroyed
public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder sHolder){
    if(camera == null){
        return;
    }
    Log.v("Surface dESTroyed ","Camera Preview");
    camera.release();

    }
    Log.v("Camera",""+camera);
}

public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int w, int h){
    Log.v("SurfaceChangesCalled", "true");
    if(camera == null){
        return;
    }

}

public void draw(Canvas canvas){
    super.draw(canvas);
    //The Paint class holds the style and color information about how to draw geometries, text and bitmaps
    Paint paint = new Paint(Color.RED);
    Log.d(TAG, "draw");
    Log.v("Draw", "Canvas");
    //Draw the text, with origin at (canvas.getWidth()/2, canvas.getHeight()/2), using the specified paint
    canvas.drawText("Preview", canvas.getWidth() / 2, canvas.getHeight() / 2, paint);
}
```

}

Now my problem is that i got ANR when my main application is open and the camera activity starts. it freezes at the line camera.release();

But when my main app is not open it works like a charm.

I also tried releasing camera in onPause() method of CameraActivity but no luck.

Comment: Which device are you using? We have the same problem on Nexus 10 and Nexus 10 only (4.3, 4.4 and 5.0 versions of android - does not happen on 4.2). The camera.release call hangs for 30 seconds. The current workaround we have is to control the camera in separate thread and then let that thread hang in background. This is not a satisfactory solution because while we wait for camera to be release we cannot use it.